# AWSGlue: can it connect the SQL Server data stores?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We found in documentation the following:
**AWS Glue can connect to the following data stores by using the JDBC protocol:
• Amazon Redshift
• Amazon Relational Database Service (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Aurora, and MariaDB)
• Publicly accessible (Amazon Redshift, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Aurora, and MariaDB) databases**

Is it possible to make a JDBC connection with SQL Server for data stores? I'm trying create to Crawler with data store in SQL Server.

Should I create new instance of SQL Server on RDS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to SQL Server using JDBC, here is a article on how to do it. 
https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/accessing-data-using-jdbc-on-aws-glue

Although it's for Salesforce, you can use the similar steps for SQL Server too. Just replace Salesforce JDBC driver with SQL Server JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if the correct JDBC driver was integrated into AWS Glue but it is not. One of the downsides of a serverless environment is you can't add drivers to the server.

Answer (score 0):

AWS reps have informed me that at present, you cannot connect to a database outside an Amazon VPC. This is obviously frustrating. I believe they are putting it on the roadmap.

If you are able to set up an RDS instance with a database they didn't explicitly name, you should try setting up a Glue job to connect to it. If it fails at first because it lacks the nece, I would imagine you should be able to connect to it by supplying the JDBC driver